# Reorder table in Google Sheets with Query or Array functions?

Tags: arrays, sorting

I have a table in Google Sheets which I have to reorder. I cannot describe my my problem so I share my problem.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OdMRP_un790afz2HQ-4l46IWtl2vbaxYuUZrxEDy_XM/edit?usp=sharing

I tried many days with different Querys and Union Querys but I had absolutely no success. I'm not sure if it's even possible to do that with a formula/query.

Many thanks for your ideas and help.